# Login 404 Parse.com REST API Java

Tags: java, android, rest, parse-platform

We decided to build our own twitter login for aesthetic reasons rather than use ParseTwitterUtils.login(), and we are having to login through the REST API (unless someone has a better idea on how to get a session token for a user with twitterAuth).

So currently it is set up as such:

```
private class ParseLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, Boolean> {

    JSONObject authData;
    JSONObject wrapper;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        try {
            authData = new JSONObject();
            wrapper = new JSONObject();
            JSONObject twitterAuth = new JSONObject();
            twitterAuth.put("id", Long.toString(twitterUser.getId()));
            twitterAuth.put("screen_name", twitterUser.getScreenName());
            twitterAuth.put("consumer_key", CONSUMER_KEY);
            twitterAuth.put("consumer_secret", CONSUMER_SECRET);
            twitterAuth.put("auth_token", accessToken.getToken());
            twitterAuth.put("auth_secret", accessToken.getTokenSecret());
            authData.put("twitter", twitterAuth);
            wrapper.put("authData", authData);


        } catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Send the HttpPostRequest and receive a JSONObject in return
        JSONObject jsonObjRecv = JSONRequest.SendHttpGet("https://api.parse.com/1/users/", wrapper);

        return true;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean response) {




    }

}
```

Which then in turns sends the login request to the REST API via here

```
public static JSONObject SendHttpPost(String URL, JSONObject jsonObjSend) {

    try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGetWithEntity httpPostRequest = new HttpGetWithEntity(URL);

        StringEntity se;
        se = new StringEntity(jsonObjSend.toString());

        // Set HTTP parameters
        httpPostRequest.setEntity(se);
        httpPostRequest.setHeader("X-Parse-Application-Id", APP KEY);
        httpPostRequest.setHeader("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", REST API KEY);
        httpPostRequest.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPostRequest.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
        HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpPostRequest);
        Log.i(TAG, "HTTPResponse received in [" + (System.currentTimeMillis()-t) + "ms]");

        // Get hold of the response entity (-> the data):
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        if (entity != null) {
            // Read the content stream
            InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
            Header contentEncoding = response.getFirstHeader("Content-Encoding");
            if (contentEncoding != null && contentEncoding.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("gzip")) {
                instream = new GZIPInputStream(instream);
            }

            // convert content stream to a String
            String resultString= convertStreamToString(instream);
            Log.d("JSON RESULT", resultString);
            instream.close();
            resultString = resultString.substring(1,resultString.length()-1); // remove wrapping "[" and "]"

            // Transform the String into a JSONObject
            JSONObject jsonObjRecv = new JSONObject(resultString);
            // Raw DEBUG output of our received JSON object:
            Log.i(TAG,"<JSONObject>\n"+jsonObjRecv.toString()+"\n</JSONObject>");

            return jsonObjRecv;
```

Any ideas on the 404?

Edit: Fixed - Use /Users/ instead of /Login/ for 3rd party auth, changes from GET to POST

```
  private class ParseLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, Boolean> {

    JSONObject authData;
    JSONObject wrapper;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        try {
            authData = new JSONObject();
            wrapper = new JSONObject();
            JSONObject twitterAuth = new JSONObject();
            twitterAuth.put("id", Long.toString(twitterUser.getId()));
            twitterAuth.put("screen_name", twitterUser.getScreenName());
            twitterAuth.put("consumer_key", CONSUMER_KEY);
            twitterAuth.put("consumer_secret", CONSUMER_SECRET);
            twitterAuth.put("auth_token", accessToken.getToken());
            twitterAuth.put("auth_token_secret", accessToken.getTokenSecret());
            authData.put("twitter", twitterAuth);
            wrapper.put("authData", authData);


        } catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Send the HttpPostRequest and receive a JSONObject in return
        JSONObject jsonObjRecv = JSONRequest.SendHttpGet("https://api.parse.com/1/users/", wrapper);

        return true;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean response) {

    }
```

And then the Get (which is actually a post, just need to changed the method name)

```
public static JSONObject SendHttpGet(String URL, JSONObject jsonObjSend) {

    try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPostRequest = new HttpPost(URL);

        StringEntity se;
        se = new StringEntity(jsonObjSend.toString());

        // Set HTTP parameters
        httpPostRequest.setEntity(se);
        httpPostRequest.setHeader("X-Parse-Application-Id", APP ID);
        httpPostRequest.setHeader("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", REST API KEY);
        httpPostRequest.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPostRequest.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        //httpPostRequest.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip"); // only set this parameter if you would like to use gzip compression

        long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
        HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpPostRequest);
        Log.i(TAG, "HTTPResponse received in [" + (System.currentTimeMillis()-t) + "ms]");

        // Get hold of the response entity (-> the data):
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        if (entity != null) {
            // Read the content stream
            InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
            Header contentEncoding = response.getFirstHeader("Content-Encoding");
            if (contentEncoding != null && contentEncoding.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("gzip")) {
                instream = new GZIPInputStream(instream);
            }

            // convert content stream to a String
            String resultString= convertStreamToString(instream);
            Log.d("JSON RESULT", resultString);
            instream.close();
            resultString = resultString.substring(1,resultString.length()-1); // remove wrapping "[" and "]"

            // Transform the String into a JSONObject
            JSONObject jsonObjRecv = new JSONObject(resultString);
            // Raw DEBUG output of our received JSON object:
            Log.i(TAG,"<JSONObject>\n"+jsonObjRecv.toString()+"\n</JSONObject>");

            return jsonObjRecv;
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // More about HTTP exception handling in another tutorial.
        // For now we just print the stack trace.
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Is there any chance you can include details such as the specific error response you're getting, the URL you're POSTing too, and so on? Have you tried out the API using curl with known good values to ensure that the REST API request is well-formed?

Comment: Hey Hector, just posted the answer above.

Comment: Instead of more code, can you post the specifics I mentioned?

Comment: It's already fixed. I was getting 404, then 400, and then I figured it out. 

It should have been a POST to /Users/ instead of a GET from /Login/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. Should have been a POST to /Users/ rather than a GET from /Login/. Sharing incase anyone else runs into this.

private class ParseLogin extends AsyncTask {

```
    JSONObject authData;
    JSONObject wrapper;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        try {
            authData = new JSONObject();
            wrapper = new JSONObject();
            JSONObject twitterAuth = new JSONObject();
            twitterAuth.put("id", Long.toString(twitterUser.getId()));
            twitterAuth.put("screen_name", twitterUser.getScreenName());
            twitterAuth.put("consumer_key", CONSUMER_KEY);
            twitterAuth.put("consumer_secret", CONSUMER_SECRET);
            twitterAuth.put("auth_token", accessToken.getToken());
            twitterAuth.put("auth_token_secret", accessToken.getTokenSecret());
            authData.put("twitter", twitterAuth);
            wrapper.put("authData", authData);


        } catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Send the HttpPostRequest and receive a JSONObject in return
        JSONObject jsonObjRecv = JSONRequest.SendHttpGet("https://api.parse.com/1/users/", wrapper);

        return true;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean response) {

    }
```

And then the Get (which is actually a post, just need to changed the method name)

```
public static JSONObject SendHttpGet(String URL, JSONObject jsonObjSend) {

    try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPostRequest = new HttpPost(URL);

        StringEntity se;
        se = new StringEntity(jsonObjSend.toString());

        // Set HTTP parameters
        httpPostRequest.setEntity(se);
        httpPostRequest.setHeader("X-Parse-Application-Id", APP ID);
        httpPostRequest.setHeader("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", REST API KEY);
        httpPostRequest.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPostRequest.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        //httpPostRequest.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip"); // only set this parameter if you would like to use gzip compression

        long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
        HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpPostRequest);
        Log.i(TAG, "HTTPResponse received in [" + (System.currentTimeMillis()-t) + "ms]");

        // Get hold of the response entity (-> the data):
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        if (entity != null) {
            // Read the content stream
            InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
            Header contentEncoding = response.getFirstHeader("Content-Encoding");
            if (contentEncoding != null && contentEncoding.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("gzip")) {
                instream = new GZIPInputStream(instream);
            }

            // convert content stream to a String
            String resultString= convertStreamToString(instream);
            Log.d("JSON RESULT", resultString);
            instream.close();
            resultString = resultString.substring(1,resultString.length()-1); // remove wrapping "[" and "]"

            // Transform the String into a JSONObject
            JSONObject jsonObjRecv = new JSONObject(resultString);
            // Raw DEBUG output of our received JSON object:
            Log.i(TAG,"<JSONObject>\n"+jsonObjRecv.toString()+"\n</JSONObject>");

            return jsonObjRecv;
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // More about HTTP exception handling in another tutorial.
        // For now we just print the stack trace.
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Is this an answer to your question? If not, don't post it in the answer section. Instead you can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24790870/edit) your question.